# "Der Vogel war aber kein gewöhnlicher, sondern so wunderbarer Art, daß..."

Tags: sentence-structure, grammatical-case, noun

This post is on the two words as highlighted in this excerpt from [Die zwei Brüder](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Die_zwei_Br%C3%BCder_(1857)) as collected by Brothers Grimm.

> Der Goldschmied war klug und listig und wußte wohl, was das für ein Vogel war. Er rief seine Frau und sprach „brat mir den Goldvogel und sorge, daß nichts davon wegkommt; ich habe Lust, ihn ganz allein zu essen.“ Der Vogel war aber kein **gewöhnlicher**, sondern so **wunderbarer** Art, daß, wer Herz und Leber von ihm aß, jeden Morgen ein Goldstück unter seinem Kopfkissen fand.

**QUESTION**

Am I right to think that *gewöhnlicher* is in the nominative and *wunderbarer* in the genitive?

That is, should I read the sentence as:

> Der Vogel war aber kein **gewöhnlicher** [Vogel], sondern [ein Vogel] so **wunderbarer** Art, daß...

Comment: Yes, you read the sentence correct.

Comment: But if you change "kein" to "nicht" both adjectives would be genitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the nominative *gewöhnlicher* doesn't need any explanation - It refers to *Vogel* which is nominative, so all should be clear.

What you see in *wunderbarer Art* is a construct that is called *genitivus qualitatis* (genitive of quality). The adjective *wunderbar* qualifies the substantive *Art* here, which is in genitive to express a trait of the referred substantive *Vogel*, like in

> Fahrkarte zweiter Klasse
>
> Freude kurzer Dauer

In English, this would be expressed with a preposition + dative, namely "of":

> The bird was not a usual one, but rather of such a wonderful kind that whoever ate ...

and German can, alternatively to the above, do the same:

> der Vogel war kein gewöhnlicher, sondern von so wunderbarer Art, dass

Comment: There is no dative in English.

Comment: @RHa methinks there is. At least a tiny bit. Translate to *objective case*, if you like. Dative mainly refers to the German example.

Answer (score 1):

- **Was** war er? (Nominativ question): ein *gewöhnlicher* Vogel (adjective description of the bird)
- **Welcher** Art war er? (Genitiv question): *wunderbarer* Art (which species/kind (German: Art) does it derives from? => derivation is genitive  casus)

Yes, you are right.

Comment: This "question-based" derivation of cases is pretty useless for non-native speakers. If they don't know how to say it, how should they know how to ask for it?